# EmberJS, how to observe changes in any object of a hash

Tags: ember.js, computed-properties

I have an Object like:

```
// app/services/my-service.js
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Service.extend({
  counters: Ember.Object.create()
})
```

`myService.counters` is a *hash* like:

```
{
  clocks: 3,
  diamons: 2
}
```

I want to add a *computed attribute* to this object such returns the sum of `myService.counters.clocks` plus `myService.counters.diamons`

```
// app/services/my-service.js
...
count: Ember.computed('counters.@each', function(){
  return _.reduce(this.get('counters'), function(memo, num){ return memo + num; }, 0);
})
...
```

But the observer configuration is not accepted and I have the error:

```
Uncaught Error: Assertion Failed: Depending on arrays using a dependent key ending with `@each` is no longer supported. Please refactor from `Ember.computed('counters.@each', function() {});` to `Ember.computed('counters.[]', function() {})`.
```

But if I make the proposed change:

```
// app/services/my-service.js
...
count: Ember.computed('counters.[]', function(){
  return _.reduce(this.get('counters'), function(memo, num){ return memo + num; }, 0);
})
...
```

The *count* attribute is not updated.

The only way I can make it work is like this:

```
// app/services/my-service.js
...
count: Ember.computed('counters.clocks', 'counters.diamons', function(){
  return _.reduce(this.get('counters'), function(memo, num){ return memo + num; }, 0);
})
...
```

How can I use any kind of wildcard for this situation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`@each` and `[]` are for observing array elements and arrays.

You can't use a wildcard because it would be a serious performance sink. There is a shorthand for multiple properties:

```
count: Ember.computed('counters.{clocks,diamons}', function() {
    return this.get('counters').reduce((memo, num) => memo + num, 0);
})
```

I also updated the computed logic to use `Array#reduce`, and an arrow function with implicit return.

Comment: The problem is that I don't know beforehand which are the keys of my `counters` :/ .. this _attribute_ is manipulated out of the Class by modules that modify the values and even add new keys.

Comment: If you need to specify dependent keys of a computed property at runtime, use `defineProperty`.